# how to take sqrt in sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

This is the query of PHP using MySQL. can anyone please convert this query to sqlite query?

Query:

```
select SQRT(POW(latitude, 2) + POW(longitude, 2)) *110 as dist from route
```

Best Regards,
Thanks

Comment: I don't know SQLite, but as these [functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) seem to be unavailable, you could try to use another distance: `abs(latitude)+abs(longitude)`. Or just `latitude*latitude + longitude*longitude` in the query (e.g. for sorting), and perform the rest `SQRT(x)*110` in PHP.

Comment: thank you very much i have done it, the way u tell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have done it with the help of "pascal".

The query becomes:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            temperature,
            climate,
            temperatureTime,
            photoURL,
            (((latitude - 37.331689) * (latitude - 37.331689)) + (longitude - (-122.030731)) * (longitude - (-122.030731))) * (110 * 110) AS dist 
        FROM 
            weather
    )
    AS tab 
WHERE 
    tab.dist <= (1.0 * 1.0);
```

This query is used to find out the nearest coordinates of locations around me within 1 KM.

Answer (score 4):

It's trivial to register PHP's [sqrt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php) with [sqlite_create_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-create-function.php).

```
sqlite_create_function($sqlite_db, "sqrt", "sqrt", 1);
```

Without registering, you can use:

```
php('sqrt', value);
```