# How can i query in mysql-table(where lat and long stored) that which are the nearest location to inputed location(lat and long)?

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, gps

I want to make an application in android. In this app user have to register in this app. With the registration the gps location(lat and long) will store in database table with user info. In this app i want to add a functionality that is "Search People who are in Root". User can input starting point and ending point(like : Mumbai to Delhi). And every peoples between this two point want to be found.

For Example : User-A have newly registered in this app. User-A's gps location is like lat = 20.234554 and long = 56.21455255. Now he will input two point like mumbai to delhi and click search button. Now i want to query in the database where every peoples information has been already stored. I want to query in database that "Select * from Location(Table) where peoples between mumbai to delhi"

Database table "locations" has four field id, lat, long and cityname. Now i want the above query on the database where i can find the people those are between the two inputted geo points.

Hope i have explained well that you understand what i want to achieve is only that i want to just search which are the nearby locations(lat and long) from the database table with inputted location(lat and long).

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368785/how-to-take-sqrt-in-sqlite

Comment: thanks i m trying it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to limit your location by some conditions which can be indexed. You can do that easily as you probably don't want to list somebody from the US to somebody in Paris as nearest location.

With just a bit modification on RustamIS query you can eliminate the most of the irrelevant locations.

```
select * from gps_location_table t 
where
    t.x between 20.134554 and 20.334554 and t.y between 56.11455255 and 56.31455255
order by 
    sqrt((t.x - 20.234554)*(t.x - 20.234554) + (t.y - 56.21455255)*(t.y - 56.21455255)
desc
```

So you defined a rectangle where you want to look for the nearest people.

Comment: See this is my php : <?php header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

  require_once("connect.php");  
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from locations t 
where
    t.lat between 20.134554 and 20.334554 and t.lont between 56.11455255 and 56.31455255
order by 
    sqrt((t.lat - 20.234554)*(t.lat - 20.234554) + (t.lont - 56.21455255)*(t.lont - 56.21455255)
desc");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
?>


but when i run it throu my local server wamp : it trows following error :

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>D:\WAMP INSTALLED\WAMP2\wamp\www\PHP\check.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
null

Comment: is this query is ok ? i have wrote it in my php file : $sql=mysql_query("select * from locations t 
where
    t.lat between 20.134554 and 20.334554 and t.lont between 56.11455255 and 56.31455255
order by 
    sqrt((t.lat - 20.234554)*(t.lat - 20.234554) + (t.lont - 56.21455255)*(t.lont - 56.21455255)
desc");

Comment: There is a missing bracket at the and of the sqrt function before the desc. 

select * from location t where t.lat between 20.134554 and 20.334554 and t.lont between 56.11455255 and 56.31455255 order by sqrt((t.lat - 20.234554)*(t.lat - 20.234554) + (t.lont - 56.21455255)*(t.lont - 56.21455255)) desc;

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN(23.037698 * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(23.037698 * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((72.564835 - longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) as distance FROM location;
```

Above query will return you the distance if you enter

```
lat = 23.037698
long = 72.564835
```

Now compare distance say distance > 50kms.

This has worked for me.

Comment: thank you for your time and get back to you, i will sure vote up if i got.........

Comment: I have write the above line in my php like : $sql=mysql_query("SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN(23.037698 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS(23.037698 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((72.564835 - lont) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) as 50 FROM location");

  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));

Comment: but this warning displayed in browser when i run php : <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>D:\WAMP INSTALLED\WAMP2\wamp\www\PHP\check.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
null

Comment: ok. I am not at all aware of php. I am an android guy. But lets make sure you are passing correct parameters. Lets once again check all. In above query 23.037698 and 72.564835 are hardcoded lat-long pair (From here I want to get distance). and latitude - longitude are fields of table location. TRY TO RUN ON MYSQL QUERY BROWSER FIRST. THEN CALL IT FROM PHP PAGE

Comment: no no i solved it, and i got all the datas also from database but i want ask some other thing now that is like if i select two gps data (lat and long) for delhi to mumbai. now i want to serach the all people between there two points from my database. how can i do that any idea ???

Answer (score 2):

let long => Y and lat => X
then query like this

```
select * from gps_location_table t 
order by 
     sqrt(pow((t.x - 20.234554),2) + pow((t.y - 56.21455255),2))
desc
```

answer must be something like this!!! Mention that this formula does not return correct distance, but it works, and works faster than calculating real distance.

the main meaning is that the distance between two cordinates is:

```
sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
```

Comment: this query will result starting the nearest cordinates

Comment: This definitely will work but I'm afraid with increasing table size the performance will drop exponentially and will become CPU and IO intensive as MySQL has to do full table scan and order by a function's output which cannot be indexed and in addition doing a mathematical calculation on all row will consume a lot of cpu cycles.

Comment: Mention that this formula does not return correct distance, But it's consequence is correct, and it works faster because it hadn't finished all calc.(it hadn't calculated the real distance!)

Comment: yes, with the above query i have get all the recored and locations those are stored in my database....